# No connectivity between hosts on UDP port

Tags: networking, router, wireshark, udp

Host with IP address 192.168.212.49 is not able to reach host with IP address 10.50.140.179 via UDP 4501 port. ICMP (ping) communication is possible. There are two routers between these hosts.

Note: there are no ACLs nor firewalls implemented on any host and router so all flow/traffic is allowed from security point of view.

Why this happens and how to fix/reconfigure it?

[image: Overview diagram and screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried using telnet or nmap to verify that port?

Comment: in destination hosts does `ss -ulp` show a program listening on port 4501 ? does `nc -u 127.0.0.1 4501` or `nc -u 10.50.140.179 4501` work ?

Answer (score 0):

ICMP is allowed by default on the device 10.50.140.179 and 10.50.140.179 is listening for this communication.

There must be a program that is listening to port UDP 4501 so that you can get a response from 10.50.140.179.

Comment: Note that LISTENING is mostly related to TCP connections. For UDP, the port must have been opened by the process, but it won't be in a "LISTENING" state. as long as `netstat -a |  grep 4501` returns a port and a process, that should suffice.